# Keeping middle item centered horizontally

Tags: html, css, header

I'm trying to make my first custom header.

I want the middle item (eg. the logo) to stay **centered** regardless of how much content is on either side.

I tried using `z-index` but I believe that was wrong.

HTML:

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-item {
  text-align: center;
}

.image {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="header_container">
  <div id="header">

    <ul class="flex-container">
      <li class="flex-item">Menu items 1 BHello | seven | eight | nineteen | Fitiyytwooooo
      </li>
      <li class="image">
        <img src="http://www.plankdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/html4.jpg" style="width:204px;height:128px;">
      </li>
      <li class="flex-item">Menu items 2 Blah | Blah | Blah</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4078d3zg/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4078d3zg/2/)**

```
.image img {
    z-index: 1000;
    width:18%;
    height:128px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-9%; /* half of the width */
}
```

HTML:

```
 <li class="image">
   <img src="http://www.plankdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/html4.jpg" />
 </li>
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Thank you. Now to make it mobile responsive. Any tips where to start or good fiddles to check out?

Comment: On my site (blank HTML5 WP theme) the header content is not "on top" (so when I scroll, it gets messy). Can you suggest a fix?

Comment: Unfortunetly I'm using WAMP so I can't. It only seems to happen on the woocommerce item photo's & details (not headings or other text on the page)

Comment: I'd also like the two left & right parts to be closer aligned to the margins (a 15% gap from each side). How is this possible? I've updated my fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/4078d3zg/4/)

Comment: can you show your expected output as image representation? like this u want http://jsfiddle.net/4078d3zg/6/

Comment: Nope, but thanks. I just want to bring the text elements closer to the edge of the header. I still want the header to be full width. http://jsfiddle.net/4078d3zg/7/

Answer (score 0):

[Check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/60qn0d45/), you may want to modify the code(`col-md-x`) as per your requirement.